# PyQt4 - function have not executed which connected to a signal

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

As title, I use
 `self.connect(MorePushButton, SIGNAL("clicked"), MorePushButton_toggled)` 
and
`self.connect(MorePushButton, SIGNAL("clicked"), self.MoreFrame.setVisible)`

to execute the function "MorePushButton_toggled" and set property when MorePushButton clicked.

But, here's the problem I can't figure out:
when I pushed the button **MorePushButton**, it did nothing!
And it also had no error message.
Did I put the code on the wrong side?
If someone can help me, I would appreciate!

Here's my code below:

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from ui_extention2 import Ui_Dialog

    class Main(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
            self.connect(MorePushButton, SIGNAL("clicked"), MorePushButton_toggled)
            self.connect(MorePushButton, SIGNAL("clicked"), self.MoreFrame.setVisible)
            self.setupUi(self)


    def MorePushButton_toggled(self):
        if self.MorePushButton.isChecked() == True:
            #self.Dialog.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0,400,280))
            Dialog.resize(400, 280)
            print("Resize 400*280")
        else:
            #self.Dialog.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0,400,100))
            Dialog.resize(400, 100)
            print("Resize 400*100")




    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        Dialog.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Remark:
(1)the .ui file was designed by QT Designer
(2)Python version:4.3
(3)PyQt version:GPL 4.11.4

Comment: `SIGNAL("clicked()")`

Comment: I tried. It did nothing, too.